Coq 8.18 is not starting on Windows 10 - How to troubleshoot?
I have installed Coq on Windows 10 and I have managed to run and use it one time. But I was in need to restart my laptop and I hard-terminated Coq. Now I have restarted my computer and I am trying to run it again, but it just silently exits:
C:\Coq-Platform~8.18~2023.11>coq-shell.bat
"Using coqc from C:\Coq-Platform~8.18~2023.11\\bin"

There is no logs in the Coq directory, no events in the Windows Event viewer, I have not checked AppData so far. Is there a way to troubleshoot my installation of Coq?
I am ware that AVG tried to delete on dll, but only very few antivirus software pieces reported it as malicious, so - I made AVG exception for this dll. But still - maybe there are some other issues that I can correct myself if only I knew what is preventing the start?
